# Веб-приложение не находит представления

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-core

Прям какая-то беда с публикацией моего сайта. Небольшая предыстория:
[Невалидный файл конфигурации web.config](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844624/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-web-config?noredirect=1#comment1356174_844624)

При запуске напрямую опубликованного веб-приложения с помощью команды dotnet eshop.dll и обращении к нему, в консоль пишется следующая ошибка:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0] An unhandled exception has occurred: The layout view '/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml' could not be located. The following locations were searched: /Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml

Список файлов в папке, куда опубликован сайт[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему возникает данная ошибка, если есть библиотека с прекомпилированными вью?

Comment: А разве в `asp.net core` используется `web.config`? От него же отказались в пользу `appsettings.json`? Вот он у вас даже виден в списке файлов.

Comment: @Bulson при разработке его нет в папках проекта, но вот при публикации появляется

Comment: А  это [ASP.NET Core Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1) вы устанавливали?

Comment: @Bulson он запускает напрямую, а не через iis. И даже под iis - без модуля бы упало гораздо раньше,  а не на рендеринге вью.

Comment: при запуске из студии по Ctrl+f5 работает? в файле csproj есть какие-нибудь упоминания Layout.cshtml или вообще папки Views?

Comment: @PashaPash работает, в файле есть два упоминания:
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Views\Shared\Layout.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Views\Shared\Layout.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH ну вот эти Content Remove и убирают файлы из окончательной сборки. Удалите их

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, заработало

Comment: @PashaPash можете оформить комментарий в виде ответа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в файле csproj убрать строчку

`<Content Remove="Views\Shared\Layout.cshtml" />`